Terraform AWS VPC Endpoint module - How to enable both Interface and Gateway endpoints?
DynamoDB now supports both Interface Endpoint and Gateway Endpoint. How we can enable both using AWS VPC Endpoints Terraform sub-module?
The code below only created an Interface VPC Endpoint.
module "endpoints" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws//modules/vpc-endpoints"

  vpc_id             = "vpc-12345678"
  security_group_ids = ["sg-12345678"]

  endpoints = {
    dynamodb = {
      service             = "dynamodb"
      private_dns_enabled = false
    },
    dynamodb = {
      service         = "dynamodb"
      route_table_ids = ["rtb-0a699a4d82df52a0e"]
    }
  }
}

